# Error when cloning a SQL Server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

So when I try this code (one line at a time):

```
BACKUP DATABASE [test] TO  DISK = N'C:\test\test.bak' WITH  INIT ,  NOUNLOAD ,  NAME = N'Test backup',  NOSKIP ,  STATS = 10,  NOFORMAT 
RESTORE DATABASE [test2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\test\test.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'test_Data' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\test2.MDF',  MOVE N'test_Log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\test2_log.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

The first line works, the .bak file is created and the query is successful. Then I try the second line above, and I get this error:

```
Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Logical file 'test_Data' is not part of database 'test2'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The code that I'm trying came from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/d24f68ee-f186-4788-884f-04c2faf17109/).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Test_Data' is most likely not the name of the logical file that contains the data in the database that has been backed up.  Use `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` as suggested to determine the name of this file - or right-click on the database from which the backup was taken and look at the properties - where you can view the names of the file(s) associated with the database.

If 'Test_Data' *is* the correct logical file name then most likely you have more than one backup stored in the one .bak file.  Try restoring through SSMS rather than T-SQL to get a better feel for what you're dealing with - you can always script out the restore, rather than running it, to see how it should've been scripted.